# Java Regex - Match line word that not inside string

Tags: java, regex, string, class

For my project, I want to get class using regex but not inside string

for e.g

```
class fo{
    void foo{
        System.out.println("example writing of class");
        System.out.println("class cls{");
    }
}
```

so, I hope result like this :

```
class fo{
```

I have try create a pattern but not working, Here.

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(?!(\"))class\\s+\\w+\\{\\b(?!(\"))")
```

Comment: that's great, put on your post, and i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|\\n)\\s*class.*
```

Explaining:

```
(?:^|\\n)       # from start or new line
\\s*            # as many as possible spaces
class           # the 'class' text
.*              # all characters till the end of line
```

Hope it helps.